# Jinja2 looping through dict with control over what key:value is used

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to create a table in HTML from data passed to the web as dict

app.py:

```
client = boto3.client('ec2')
vpc_ids = client.describe_vpcs()
for i in vpc_ids.get('Vpcs'):
    for tag in i.get('Tags'):
        if tag.get('Key') == 'Name':
            vpc_list[i.get('VpcId')] = {'CidrBlock': i.get('CidrBlock'), 
            'Name': tag.get('Value')}
return vpc_list
```

This returnes dict like this:

```
vpc_list = {'vpc-1': {'CidrBlock': 'x.x.x.x/16', 'Name': 'a-vpc'},
            'vpc-2': {'CidrBlock': 'y.y.y.y/16', 'Name': 'b-vpc'},
            'vpc-3': {'CidrBlock': 'z.z.z.z/16', 'Name': 'c-vpc'},
            'vpc-4': {'CidrBlock': 'q.q.q.q/16', 'Name': 'd-vpc'}}
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
{% if vpc_lists is defined %}
{% for vpc, data in vpc_lists.items() %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        {{vpc}}
    </div>
    {% for key,value in data.items() %}
    <div class="col-md-3">
        {{value}}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <a href="/vpc/{{vpc}}">Link</a>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

The Above works... kind off, but I would like better control over how and where I can use key values, so instead of just blindly looping through this I would like to be able to get a value based on the key, something like

```
vpc.get('CidrBlock') or vpc['CidrBlock'] to get the x.x.x.x/16 value.
```

Not sure if I'm making it clear enough. I couldn't find anything like this in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jinja supports dictionary access syntax, you can use `{{data['CidrBlock']}}` and `{{data['Name']}}` to access specific values in your dictionary.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was much easier than I expected!